# How to get model validations to talk with view layer in Rails to provide simple functionality?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, view, model

I have a `Room` model that validates that its room number is unique. However, when a user is creating a new `Room` instance, if they try and create a room that already exists, instead of displaying the standard *this room already exists* error message, I would like to provide a link to that room so that they can edit it. Ex: I would like the error message to say: *room x already exists. **Click here** to edit that room.* where the Click Here text is a link to that room object's edit path.

Is there a way to do this or something similar in Rails? Any advice would be much appreciated!

Comment: Off the top of my head, you could raise an error in the validation if it fails and catch that error in the controller. If the controller catches it, you can render a special view containing the link to edit the room.

Comment: Seems like it could be done with Ajax or more simply using `before_create` validation to return "Room `#{@room.number}` already exists" and redirects the user to an update page for that `Room` if the number is not unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the client_side_validations gem https://github.com/bcardarella/client_side_validations to use your ruby validations in javascript (if you're using jquery) like shown in railscast #263 http://railscasts.com/episodes/263-client-side-validations.

You can create a custom validator, that finds the existing room_id and pass a link to it on to your error message that is returned to your view, something like:

```
# lib/room_existence_validator.rb
class RoomExistenceValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(object, attribute, value)
    if existing_room = Room.find_by_id(value)
      # unfortunately url_for helper is not defined here so it's hard-wired
      room_link = "/rooms/#{existing_room.id}/edit"
      object.errors[attribute] << "#{link_to "Click here", room_link} to edit that room"
    end
  end
end
```

You need to add the :validates => true part to your form_for helper call.
Now it works without ajaxified calls.

To make it work with ajax, there are 2 more things to do:

a) add a rails.validations.custom.js file, that could look something like this:

```
# rails.validations.custom.js
# please beware the .remote in function-name
ClientSideValidations.validators.remote['existing_room'] = function(element, options) {
  if ($.ajax({
    url: '/validators/existing_room',
    data: { id: element.val() },
    // async *must* be false
    async: false
  }).status == 404) { return options.message; }
}
```

b) route your validation-request e.g. by adding a rack middleware that respondes to your validators-routes as described in the client_side_validations wiki https://github.com/bcardarella/client_side_validations/wiki/Custom-Validators

Hope that helps :D